# Need to collapse out the search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have my HTML File

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary" 
     id="collapseOne_container">
  <div class="panel-heading" 
       role="tab" 
       id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-parent="#accordion" 
         href="#collapseOne" 
         aria-expanded="false" 
         aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <b>Planning</b> (1)
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" 
       class="panel-collapse collapse" 
       role="tabpanel" 
       aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Using schema</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary" 
     id="collapseTwo_Container">
  <div class="panel-heading" 
       role="tab" 
       id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" 
         role="button" 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-parent="#accordion" 
         href="#collapseTwo" 
         aria-expanded="false" 
         aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <b>Outage 2</b> (1)
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" 
       class="panel-collapse collapse" 
       role="tabpanel" 
       aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Using schema</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have my JQuery:-

```
(function(){
     var searchTerm, panelContainerId;
      $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function (n, i, m) {
      return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) 
          >= 0;
        };

      $('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function 
   () {
       searchTerm = $(this).val();
       $('#accordion > .panel').each(function () {
       panelContainerId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
      $(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm 
     + 
       '))').hide();
     $(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + 
     $("#accordion > .panel").collapse in('show');
     });
   });
   }());
```

I am successfully able to search, and display result. 
The required search result must be in expanded accordion with accordion body content displayed in the result which includes image and paragraph.

I tried with collapse in('show').
This is not working fine. Can i get help in this.

Comment: It's a little unclear, but it sounds like when a search is performed, results are appended to a panel and that panel is collapsed or needs to be collapsed? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<button class="collapsible">Option 1</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>Using schema one</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Option 2</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>Using schema two</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Option 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Using schema three </p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. but am looking for the search function to display with panel body.